# puppeteer cannot get hidden element and also cannnot get the value from hidden element

Tags: puppeteer

I failed to use puppeteer to get the value from hidden element.

```
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    page = await browser.newPage( )
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com")
    element = await page.waitForSelector('input[type="hidden"][name="newwindow"]', {
        hidden: true,
        timeout: 15000,
    })
    data = await  page.$eval('input[name="newwindow"]', ({ value }) => value);
```

I got below error. Can anyone help me?

```
Uncaught Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "input[name="newwindow"]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seem to happen at the last line where you're using the selector "input[name="newwindow"]".

It means that the previous line does work with `input[type="hidden"][name="newwindow"]` and your element is instanciated in the variable `element`.

You can then use this variable to get the text:

```js
const dataHandle = await element.getProperty("innerText");
const data = dataHandle._remoteObject.value;
```

if you don't want to use the variable and keep using `$eval`, I believe updating the last line this way should work:

```js
data = await page.$eval('input[type="hidden"][name="newwindow"]', ({ value }) => value);
```